# Nginx proxy_bind failing

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, iptables, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm attempting to configure nginx to reverse proxy requests from (192.168.0.2:12345) the same Internal Host Address that it's listening from  (192.168.0.2:443) on separate ports using the listen and proxy_bind directives.

```
# /opt/sbin/nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.19.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

# ifconfig br0:0 192.168.0.2

# opkg install nginx-ssl
# opkg install ca-bundle
```

```
# cat /opt/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user admin root;
#user nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  64;
}

http {
    # HTTPS server

    server {
        listen       192.168.0.2:443 ssl;
        server_name  $host;

        ssl_certificate        /etc/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/key.pem;
        ssl_client_certificate /opt/etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_verify_client optional;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;

        proxy_ssl_server_name      on;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
            resolver 103.86.99.100;
    #        proxy_bind 192.168.0.2:12345;
            proxy_bind $server_addr:12345;
    #        proxy_bind $remote_addr:12345 transparent;
            proxy_pass $scheme://$host;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the `user admin root;` which is the root user for this router.  I've tried using different combinations of `proxy_bind 192.168.0.2;`, `proxy_bind 192.168.0.2 transparent;`, `proxy_bind $server_addr;`, and `proxy_bind $server_addr transparent;`.  None of them appear to work, when validating with tcpdump.  nginx always uses the External WAN Address (100.64.8.236).

Ifconfig Output:

```
# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:56:27:D1:B8:A4
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10243803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5440860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:14614392834 (13.6 GiB)  TX bytes:860977246 (821.0 MiB)

br0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:56:27:D1:B8:A4
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

vlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:56:27:D1:B8:A4
          inet addr:100.64.8.236  Bcast:100.64.15.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1757588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:613625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2267961441 (2.1 GiB)  TX bytes:139435610 (132.9 MiB)
```

Route Output:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.0.17      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun12
89.38.98.142    100.64.8.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 vlan2
100.64.8.1      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 vlan2
10.15.0.65      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun11
192.168.2.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 vlan3
51.68.180.4     100.64.8.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 vlan2
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan3
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
100.64.8.0      *               255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         100.64.8.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
```

Tcpdump Output:

Client Remote_Addr (192.168.0.154:$port) == Request => Nginx Reverse Proxy Server - Listener (192.168.0.2:443)

```
07:19:06.840468  In c8:1f:66:13:a1:11 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: 192.168.0.154.55138 > 192.168.0.2.443: Flags [.], ack 1582, win 8212, length 0
07:19:06.840468  In c8:1f:66:13:a1:11 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: 192.168.0.154.55138 > 192.168.0.2.443: Flags [.], ack 1582, win 8212, length 0
```

Nginx Reverse Proxy Server - Listener (192.168.0.2:443) == Response => Client Remote_Addr (192.168.0.154:$port)

```
07:19:06.841377 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 56: 192.168.0.2.443 > 192.168.0.154.55138: Flags [.], ack 1475, win 541, length 0
07:19:06.841411 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 56: 192.168.0.2.443 > 192.168.0.154.55138: Flags [.], ack 1475, win 541, length 0
```

Nginx Reverse Proxy Server - Sender (100.64.8.236:12345) == Request => Upstream Desination Server - Listener (104.27.161.206:443)

```
07:19:11.885314 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 100.64.8.236.12345 > 104.27.161.206.443: Flags [S], seq 3472185855, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 331214 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
```

Upstream Desination Server - Listener (104.27.161.206:443) == Response => Nginx Reverse Proxy Server - Sender (100.64.8.236:12345)

```
07:19:11.887683  In 02:1f:a0:00:00:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 104.27.161.206.443 > 100.64.8.236.12345: Flags [S.], seq 2113436779, ack 3472185856, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
```

Note: The Nginx Reverse Proxy Server (Listener) and Nginx Reverse Proxy Server (Sender) MAC addresses are the same piece of hardware

```
07:19:06.840468  In c8:1f:66:13:a1:11 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: 192.168.0.154.55138 > 192.168.0.2.443: Flags [.], ack 1582, win 8212, length 0
07:19:06.840468  In c8:1f:66:13:a1:11 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: 192.168.0.154.55138 > 192.168.0.2.443: Flags [.], ack 1582, win 8212, length 0
07:19:06.841377 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 56: 192.168.0.2.443 > 192.168.0.154.55138: Flags [.], ack 1475, win 541, length 0
07:19:06.841411 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 56: 192.168.0.2.443 > 192.168.0.154.55138: Flags [.], ack 1475, win 541, length 0
07:19:11.885314 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 100.64.8.236.12345 > 104.27.161.206.443: Flags [S], seq 3472185855, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 331214 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
07:19:11.887683  In 02:1f:a0:00:00:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 104.27.161.206.443 > 100.64.8.236.12345: Flags [S.], seq 2113436779, ack 3472185856, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
07:19:11.887948 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 56: 100.64.8.236.12345 > 104.27.161.206.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 365, length 0
07:19:11.888854 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 264: 100.64.8.236.12345 > 104.27.161.206.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:209, ack 1, win 365, length 208
07:19:11.890844  In 02:1f:a0:00:00:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: 104.27.161.206.443 > 100.64.8.236.12345: Flags [.], ack 209, win 66, length 0
07:19:11.893154  In 02:1f:a0:00:00:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1516: 104.27.161.206.443 > 100.64.8.236.12345: Flags [.], seq 1:1461, ack 209, win 66, length 1460
07:19:11.893316 Out c0:56:27:d1:b8:a4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 56: 100.64.8.236.12345 > 104.27.161.206.443: Flags [.], ack 1461, win 548, length 0
07:19:11.893161  In 02:1f:a0:00:00:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1000: 104.27.161.206.443 > 100.64.8.236.12345: Flags [P.], seq 1461:2405, ack 209, win 66, length 944
```

Iptables Output:

```
# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i vlan2 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 12345 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2000/0x2000
# iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -o vlan2 -p tcp -m multiport --sport 12345 -j MARK --set-mark 0x8000/0x8000
```

Note: Packets are matching and being marked, but not being routed to the appropriate interfaces. I'm thinking it may be too late in the pipe.

```
# iptables -t mangle -L -v -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5506K packets, 8051M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   33 15329 MARK       tcp  --  vlan2  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 12345 MARK or 0x2000

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2832K packets, 171M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   30  4548 MARK       tcp  --  *      vlan2   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport sports 12345 MARK or 0x8000
```

The reverse proxied requests make it to the destination and back, but using the External WAN Address (100.64.8.236:12345) and not the Internal Host Address (192.168.0.2:12345).

EDIT: I discovered a single SYN packet being sent from 192.168.0.2:12345 (nginx worker) when initiating traffic. Nothing more with no repsonse.  I'm wondering if 192.168.0.2:12345 doesn't receive a SYN,ACK is the nginx worker using the next available interface address (i.e., 100.64.8.236:12345)?

```
# netstat -anp|grep 12345
tcp 0 1 192.168.0.2:12345 172.64.163.36:443 SYN_SENT 14176/nginx: worker
```

My goal is to use iptables to MARK the 192.168.0.2:12345 packets for routing over an established OpenVPN Tunnel (tun12).

The proxy_bind directive just seems to be failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've confirmed that I am only able to change the sending address if I use the proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent combination and that will only rewrite to the originating client address. I've also noticed that I'm able to define the sending port with the proxy_bind directive, but I'm still unable to rewrite the sending address to the $server_addr.  I've validated that the 192.168.0.2:443 address is listening on the br0:0 interface and the 100.64.8.236:$port is sending from the vlan2 interface.  The br0:0 & vlan2 use the same mac address. I just can't get nginx to send from the $server_addr.

Comment: I discovered a single SYN packet being sent from 192.168.0.2:12345 (nginx worker) when initiating traffic. Nothing more. # netstat -anp|grep 12345 tcp 0 1 192.168.0.2:12345 172.64.163.36:443 SYN_SENT 14176/nginx: worker Question: If 192.168.0.2:12345 doesn't receive a SYN,ACK will the nginx worker use the next available interface address (i.e., 100.64.8.236:12345)? My goal is to use iptables to MARK the 192.168.0.2:12345 packets for routing over an established OpenVPN Tunnel (tun12). Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All:

After reviewing the iptables chains workflow, I discovered that the Nginx Worker (192.168.0.2:12345) outside interface was associated with the OUTPUT chain.

```
                                                                                 (192.168.0.2:12345) OUTPUT ==>
    (192.168.0.154:$port) PREROUTING ==>                                   (100.64.8.236:12345) POSTROUTING ==>
Windows Client (192.168.0.154:$port) ==> Nginx Master (192.168.0.2:443) | Nginx Worker (100.64.8.236:12345) ==> Upstream Desination Server (104.27.161.206:443)
                                     <== POSTROUTING (192.168.0.2:443)                                      <== PREROUTING (104.27.161.206:443)
```

Once adding the appropriate iptables OUTPUT rule, using the correct interface (vlan2), the packets leaving the Nginx Worker (100.64.8.236:12345) were then appropriately MARKed and routed to the OpenVPN Tunnel.

```
# iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -o vlan2 -p tcp -m multiport --sport 12345 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2000/0x2000
```

Now, I just need to figure out the Nginx SSL Client CA Trust configuration and we should be in business.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Respectfully,

Gary